# PCA for non linear manifolds - Yann Lecun, Deep Learning Course, Question from a Lecture

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, pca, computer-vision, manifold-learning

I was watching the following lecture and at the very end of it, one of the students asked LeCun about using PCA for expression and pose feature extraction.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0bMe_vCZo30&t=1h35m35s

The context of the question was that faces are nonlinear manifolds and so PCA won't work.
While I'm familiar with PCA and intuitively understand why it won't work for the above goal,
I didn't understand both of the explanations LeCun gave.

Does anyone care to watch his 2min explanation and make some sense of it?

Thanks a lot!